# iPhone X simulator does not receive UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame notification

Tags: ios, notifications, keyboard, emoji

Hi this is my first post in SO.

I'm using .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame notification in order to get dynamic height of the keyboard and update other views accordingly.

But when I switch to an EMOJI or a Chinese Hand-writing keyboard in iPhone X simulator, UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame notification does not get called.

- ENGLISH keyboard ---> EMOJI keyboard ( X, not called )
- EMOJI keyboard ---> ENGLISH keyboard ( O, works fine )

It works just fine in simulators other than iPhone X (eg. iPhone 5, 6, plus..).

## adding observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector : #selector(self.keyboardWillChangeFrame(withNotification:)),
                                           name : .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,
                                           object : nil)
```

## selector method

```
@objc func keyboardFrameWillChange(withNotification notification : Notification)
{
    if let size = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    {
        print("will display EMOJI with height : \(size.height)")
    }
}
```

Only tested in iPhone X simulator and not in real device (hard to get one T_T)

XCode version : latest 9.1 (9B55)
Simulator version : iPhone X (iOS 11.0.1), iPhone X (iOS 11.1)

Comment: You're right, for some reason no keyboard notifications seem to fire when going from the English to the Emoji keyboard. I just tried it out in the iPhone X simulator and on my iPhone X device -- same results. I'm thinking it's a bug in iOS.

Comment: Thank you Tyler for having it tested in real device as I don't have one yet. Thought it was a simulator issue, turned out to be iOS issue (bug perhaps). Hope Apple fixes this in future. Thanks again.